# Merge two objects has the same key name and do a calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to organize an array which has a duplicate Value (Orange) with different Quantity values... so I want to merge the similar values and calculate the quantity.

I could do it if I use the fruit name but its random names.

```
var Orders = [
{Fruit: "Orange", Quantity: 1000},
{Fruit: "Banana", Quantity: 2000},
{Fruit: "Orange", Quantity: 6000}];

var finalOrder = [];
var Quantity = 0;

for (var i in Orders) {

        Quantity += Orders[i].Quantity;
        var Fruits = Orders[i].Fruit;

        var Order = {
            Fruit: Fruits,
            Quantity: Quantity
        }

        finalOrder.push(Order);
}

console.log(finalOrder);
```

I expect the output of

```
0: {Fruit: "Orange", Quantity: 1000}
1: {Fruit: "Banana", Quantity: 3000}
3: {Fruit: "Orange", Quantity: 9000}
```

to be

```
0: {Fruit: "Orange", Quantity: 7000}
1: {Fruit: "Banana", Quantity: 2000}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reduce into an object indexed by `Fruit`, whose values are the quantity for the associated fruit key, then take that object's values:

```js
var Orders = [{
    Fruit: "Orange",
    Quantity: 1000
  },
  {
    Fruit: "Banana",
    Quantity: 2000
  },
  {
    Fruit: "Orange",
    Quantity: 6000
  }
];

const output = Object.values(Orders.reduce((a, { Fruit, Quantity }) => {
  if (!a[Fruit]) a[Fruit] = { Fruit, Quantity };
  else a[Fruit].Quantity += Quantity;
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: that's what I got (0: {Fruit: undefined, Quantity: 9000})

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" - you should see that the output is as desired. The code works perfectly fine for me, in both Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. If you use the code in the answer verbatim, it should work for you too.

Comment: That's true the code snippet is working perfect but I'm using Chrome and that's what I got

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] that illustrates the problem - as you can see if you press the "Run code snippet" button, the output is exactly what you want. If you're getting `{Fruit: undefined`, then you are using code different from what's in the answer. You can look at it on JSFiddle too, the code works there as well: https://jsfiddle.net/cm786vdo/

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is, you take a single variable for all quantities and you do not look up for the same `Fruit`.

For this part, you need another loop and if found update `Quantity` and exit the inner loop, or add a new object to the result set.

```js
var orders = [{ Fruit: "Orange", Quantity: 1000 }, { Fruit: "Banana", Quantity: 2000 }, { Fruit: "Orange", Quantity: 6000 }],
   finalOrder = [],
   i, j;

outer: for (i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < finalOrder.length; j++) {
        if (orders[i].Fruit === finalOrder[j].Fruit) {
            finalOrder[j].Quantity += orders[i].Quantity;
            continue outer;
        }
    }
    finalOrder.push({ Fruit: orders[i].Fruit, Quantity: orders[i].Quantity });
}

console.log(finalOrder);
```

Or you could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and an easy key/value approach, because you have only two properties which works fine for this approach.

```js
var orders = [{ Fruit: "Orange", Quantity: 1000 }, { Fruit: "Banana", Quantity: 2000 }, { Fruit: "Orange", Quantity: 6000 }],
    result = Array.from(
        orders.reduce((m, { Fruit, Quantity }) => m.set(Fruit, (m.get(Fruit) || 0) + Quantity), new Map),
        ([Fruit, Quantity]) => ({ Fruit, Quantity })
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly for me as well.. Thank you